# Angular Animations is installed but I can't import it

Tags: angular, animation, npm, installation

I tried to install the Animations in my project.

```
C:\gtaui>npm install @angular/animations --save
gtaui@0.0.0 C:\gtaui
+-- @angular/animations@4.1.1
`-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@2.4.10


npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\ch
okidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@
1.1.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"}
)
npm WARN @angular/animations@4.1.1 requires a peer of @angular/core@4.1.1 but no
ne was installed.

C:\gtaui>
```

I have the library in package.json

```
{
  "name": "gtaui",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.1.1",
    "@angular/common": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/core": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/http": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/router": "^3.3.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.1",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.3.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.28.3",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0-beta.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "protractor": "~4.0.13",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "^4.3.0",
    "typescript": "~2.0.3"
  }
}
```

And after I add the animations module in application module:

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
```

I get the error:

> **ERROR in C:/gtaui/src/app/modules/app.ts (3,41): Cannot find module '@angular/pl
>   atform-browser/animations'.
>   ERROR in C:/gtaui/src/app/modules/app.ts (3,41): Cannot find module '@angular/pl
>   atform-browser/animations'.
>   webpack: Failed to compile.**

Comment: I see `"@angular/common": "^2.3.1"` Update all angular dependencies to 4.1.1

Comment: @yurzui how i do this ?

Comment: Replace all `^2.3.1` with `^4.1.1` in your `package.json` remove `node_modules/@angular` folder and run `npm i`

Comment: @yurzui i got more errors omg.

Comment: You can get config from https://github.com/alexzuza/angular-cli-lazy/blob/master/package.json#L14-L44 and probable you can update `.angular-cli.json`

Comment: Now I get You have to be inside an angular-cli project in order to use the build command.

Comment: Rename `angular-cli.json` to `.angular-cli.json` and check angular cli instructions

Answer (score 1):

It gave you a nice warning to let you know: `npm WARN @angular/animations@4.1.1 requires a peer of @angular/core@4.1.1 but none was installed.`

Update your package.json to

  `"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.1.1",
    "@angular/common": "^4.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "^4.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.1.1",
    "@angular/http": "^4.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "^4.1.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.1",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.2"
  }`

And when npm says "requires a peer of" make sure you include it in your dependencies.